# Python is printing every character?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
#Printing the original list (This was given)
a = ['spam','eggs',100,1234]
a[0:2] = [1,12]
print("This is the original list:", a)
#Prompting user to input data
b = input('Please add your first item to the list: ')
c = input('Please add your second item: ')
a[4:4] = b
a[5:5] = c
#Printing new list
print(a)
```

When I run it and add items to the list, it prints every character there, so hello becomes 'h','e','l','l','o' Even the numbers do this, could you help me fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*note* : tested only on python 2.7

the assignment operator expects an iterable in the right-hand side when you do

`a[4:4] = b`

so when you `input` a string, it treats it as an iterable and assigns each value of the iterable to the list. 
if you need to use the same code, use `[string]` for the input. else use list methods like `append`

```
Please add your first item to the list: ['srj']
Please add your second item: [2]
[1, 12, 100, 1234, 'srj', 2]
```

Comment: Thanks to you too- greatly appreciated.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, Yes your answer did cover all this better than mine. I think we were writing the answers simultaneously. Should've checked on the new answers before posting mine in search for fake internet coins :)

Comment: well spend your gold wisely ;)

Answer (score 2):

Because when you add strings to a list like that they become individual character inside the list:

```
In [5]: l = [1,2,3]

In [6]: s = "foo"

In [7]: l[1:1] = s

In [8]: l
Out[8]: [1, 'f', 'o', 'o', 2, 3]
```

If you want to add the strings to the end of the list  use `append`:

```
In [9]: l = [1,2,3]

In [10]: s = "foo"

In [11]: l.append(s)

In [12]: l
Out[12]: [1, 2, 3, 'foo']
```

Or wrap the `string` in a `list` or use `list.insert`:

```
In [16]: l[1:1] = [s] # iterates over list not the string

In [17]: l
Out[17]: [1, 'foo', 2, 3, 'foo']
In [18]: l.insert(2,"foo")
In [18]: l
Out[19]: [1, 'foo', 'foo', 2, 3, 'foo']
```